# jQuery Mobile Clickhander won't work for an instance of a custom object

Tags: jquery-mobile, event-handling, click, anchor

I am setting a click handler for an anchor tag in jQuery mobile with via reference to the handler function inside the anchor tag (I need to do it this way for reasons that are cumbersome to get into). This approach works fine if I use a string or an integer as the function parameter but if I try to input an instance of an object (as illustrated below) it doesn't work. Any advice on what I may be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.css"
    />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            function testObject() {
                this.param1;
            }

            function maketestObject(param1) {
                var result = new testObject();
                result.param1 = param1;
                return result;
            }

            var i = 0;
            var html;
            for (i = 0; i <= 5; i = i + 1) {
                var testInstance = maketestObject("test param");
                html += '<li><a href="#" data-theme="a" onclick="clickHandler(' + testInstance + '); return false;" rel="external" data-role="button">click test1</a></li>';
            }

            $("#testList").append(html);
            $("#testList").listview("refresh");

        });

        function clickHandler(e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    </script>
    <div data-role="page" class="type-interior">
        <div id="main" data-role="content">
            <ul id="testList" data-role="listview"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it works

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.css"
/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>
```

$(document).ready(function() {

```
        function testObject() {
            this.param1;
        }

        function maketestObject(param1) {
            var result = new testObject();
            result.param1 = param1;
            return result;
        }

        var i = 0;
        var html;
        for (i = 0; i <= 5; i = i + 1) {
            var testInstance = maketestObject("test param");
//var temp = "'" + testInstance+ "'";


 /// Chaged into 

            var temp = "'" + testInstance.param1  + "'";

            html += '<li><a href="#" data-theme="a" onclick="clickHandler(' + temp + '); return false;" rel="external" data-role="button">click test1</a></li>';
        }

        $("#testList").append(html);
        $("#testList").listview("refresh");

    });

    function clickHandler(e) {
        alert(e);
    }
</script>
<div data-role="page" class="type-interior">
    <div id="main" data-role="content">
        <ul id="testList" data-role="listview"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought this worked initially because this passes temp though as an object in other words alert(e) in click handler returns "[object Object]", but it loses it's fields, in other words alert(e.param1) returns "undefined".

Comment: Thanks again for all your help, I really appreciate it. What you've suggested does work, but my goal is to pass in an object that could have multiple fields all of which could be accessed in the click handler. Your suggestion is essentially just passing through a string.

Answer (score 0):

did you tryied with the .live() function 
when you add dynamically elements to the dom they dont have events so I suggest you to

```
    for (i = 0; i <= 5; i = i + 1) {
                var testInstance = maketestObject("test param");
                var temp = "'" + testInstance + "'";
                html += '<li><a href="#" data-theme="a" class="new" return false;" rel="external" data-role="button">click test1</a></li>';
            }

/*** jQuery code ****/
        $(".new").live("click",function(){
    // your code here 
    aler("it working");
    });
```

I usually do this when a button dont work for me hope that works for you!

Comment: Thanks for your response. The reason I'm trying to bind data via the <a> tag is because I need to do two separate data binds per element in a split button list. Thus far I haven't been able to accomplish this using jQuery's data binding methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achive your oal using this ..

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.css"
/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
// Create global object array ..
        var testInstanc = [];
        $(document).ready(function() {




            function testObject() {
                this.param1;
            }

            function maketestObject(param1) {
                var result = new testObject();
                result.param1 = param1;
                return result;
            }

            var i = 0;
            var html;
            for (i = 0; i <= 5; i = i + 1) {

                // var temp = "'" + testInstance + "'";
// set array to object
                 testInstanc[i] = maketestObject("test param" + i);

pass clickhandler function to your array index
                 html += '<li><a href="#" data-theme="a" onclick="clickHandler(' + i + '); return false;" rel="external" data-role="button">click test1</a></li>';
            }

            $("#testList").append(html);
            $("#testList").listview("refresh");



        });
        function clickHandler(i) {
```

// access object attribute using  testInstance array
                alert(testInstanc[i].param1);

```
        }

    </script>
    <div data-role="page" class="type-interior">
        <div id="main" data-role="content">
            <ul id="testList" data-role="listview"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Ben Pearce did you check this solution?